# Hahn-Banach separation theorem: show that $f(a)<\inf f(B)$ for all $a\in \text{int}(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

**Hahn-Banach separation Theorem.** Let $A,B$ be convex non-empty disjoint subsets of a real normed space $X$. Suppose also that $\text{int}(A)\neq \emptyset$ (non-empty interior). Then there exists a continuous linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $\sup f(A)\leq \inf f(B)$ and $f(a)<\inf f(B)$ for all $a\in \text{int}(A)$.

The proofs I have seen do not show the last claim that $f(a)<\inf f(B)$ for all $a\in \text{int}(A)$.

How can one show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f(a)=\inf(f(B))$ and $a \in \rm{int}(A)$.

Then $\sup(f(A)) \le \inf(f(B)) = f(a) \le \sup(f(A))$, hence $f(a)=\sup(f(A))$. Choose $r> 0$ such that the ball $B_r(a):=\{x \in X: \|x-a\|<r\}$ is a subset of $A$. Since $f$ is not the zero functional there is some $y \in X$ (w.l.o.g. $\|y\|=1$) such that $f(y) > 0$.
Now $a+(r/2)y \in B_r(a) \subseteq A$ and $f(a+(r/2)y) > f(a)=\sup(f(A))$, a contradiction.

Comment: But how can we show that $f$ is not the zero functional?

Comment: That's the assertion of Hahn Banach: There exists a nonzero functional such that $\sup f(A) \le \inf f(B)$. Of course the zero functional always satisfies this inequality.

Comment: Ah ... the proof I was reading did not explicitly show that $f$ was nonzero. Any hint on how to show it?

Comment: If a proof does not show that $f$ is not zero, it can't be a proof, since the zero functional always satisfies this inequality. The proof I know is rather long and technical and relies on the Hahn Banach Theorem on extension of functionals.

Comment: Right totally agree. I must have missed something.

Comment: If I define the Minkowski functional $p(x)=\inf\{\lambda>0:\frac{1}{\lambda} x \in C\}$ on $X$. Then $p<1$ on $\text{int}(C)$ right?

Comment: Right. If $x \in \rm{int} (C)$, then $x/\lambda \in C$ for some $\lambda <1$. So $p(x) < 1$.

Comment: Ok I was reading theorem 4.13 and 4.14 from these notes: https://math.gsu.edu/xye/course/fa_handout/fa_notes.pdf. Am I right in saying that $p<1$ on $\text{int}(C)$ implies that $f$ is nontrivial in both theorems?

Comment: I think yes. Since $x_0 \notin E$ in 4.13 in particular $x_0 \notin \rm{int}(E)$, so $p(x_0) \ge 1$. And the proof shows that $f(x_0)=p(x_0)$. Thus $f$ is not the zero functional.

Comment: Ok but $f$ is also not constant in both theorems right? (Since $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$). If $f$ is allowed to be constant then both theorems are  also trivial.

Comment: Right. $f$ is a linear functional, so $f(0)=0$. If $f$ is constant then $f$ is constant $0$.